# Bootstrap accordion-like group management

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have two collapsable items in a `div#footer-panels`. I'm also using `data-parent="#footer-panels"` to try and achieve the accordion effect. However, when opening another panel the other isn't closing.

Any ideas on what's wrong with my markup?

```
<div id="footer-panels">
    <div id="footer-email-signup" class="container collapse">
        <div class="row">
             <h4>Newsletter</h4>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer-follow-us" class="container collapse">
        <div class="row">
             <h4>Follow Us</h4>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<nav id="utility-nav" class="container">
    <ul class="nav-justified visible-desktop">
        <li> <a id="email-signup-link" class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#footer-panels" data-target="#footer-email-signup" href="#">Newsletter Signup <span class="dropup-caret"></span></a>

        </li>
        <li> <a id="follow-us-link" class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#footer-panels" data-target="#footer-follow-us" href="#">Follow Us <span class="dropup-caret"></span></a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/V6928/2/

EDIT (solution): you need to wrap the .collapse divs with a div that has the class .panel. See the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/V6928/3/.

Comment: Should I just delete this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is my minimal working example:

```
<div id="accordion">
    <div class="panel"> 
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">One</a>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">1 Foo</div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel"> 
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">Two</a>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">2 Bar</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/allcaps/V6928/4/)

I used the code form [getboostrap.com/javascript](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-examples). It also says:

> Using the collapse plugin, we built a simple accordion by extending
>   the *panel component*.

So you need `class='panel'`.

Comment: that seems completely random, why would I need to wrap it in a panel??? but ok....it works, thanks allcaps!